# syntax error with prepared statements mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Been messing around with this since last night at no avail.

```
createOrder($website,(int)$nVotes,(int)$timeframe,$loggedInUser->email,$server,(int)$start,$referer);
```

var_dumping these variables shows (earlier):

> string(2) "web1"  string(2) "10" string(2) "10" string(23)
>   "myemail@gmail.com" string(8) "myserver" int(1423063633) string(17)
>   "http://google.com"

and the function where there seems to be a problem is:

```
function createOrder($website,$votes,$timeframe,$user,$server,$start,$referer)
{
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;
    $time = time();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."orders (
        serverId,
        orderUser,
        targetUrl,
        nVotes,
        timeframe,
        referer,
        starting
        )
        VALUES (
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?
        )");
    file_put_contents("error.log", $mysqli->errno . $mysqli->error );
    $stmt->bind_param("sssiisi", $server, $user, $website, $votes, $timeframe, $referer, $start);
    file_put_contents("error1.log", $stmt->errno . $stmt->error );
    $stmt->execute();
    file_put_contents("error1.log", $stmt->errno . $stmt->error );
    $stmt->close();
```

nginx.error.log blames the bind_param

> "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function 
>   bind_param() on a non-object in funcs.php on line 1223

error.log blames a syntax error

```
(check the manual) for the syntax to use near 'starting

  )
                VALUES (
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?
                )' at line 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `starting` is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), and you're using it as a field name. You should wrap it in backticks:

```
    serverId,
    orderUser,
    targetUrl,
    nVotes,
    timeframe,
    referer,
    `starting`
```